# Проблемы с кодировкой на ideone

Tags: c++, кодировка, ideone

Как известно, ideone компилирует исходники на Си++ в utf8. Однако, мне нужна строка в utf16 (`wstring`). Попытался сконвертировать, но получилось что-то не то (причём конвертация из wstring в utf8 работает верно):

```
wstring_convert < codecvt_utf8_utf16 <wchar_t>, wchar_t> convert;

const char *s = "еёЁжикЕст";
wstring str = convert.from_bytes(s);

for (int q=0; s[q]; ++q) cout << (int)s[q] << ' ';
cout << endl;
for (int q=0; q<str.length(); ++q) cout << (int)str[q] << ' ';
cout << endl;
```

```
-48 -75 -47 -111 -48 -127 -48 -74 -48 -72 -48 -70 -48 -107 -47 -127 -47 -126 
13572 20740 260 13828 14340 14852 5380 16644 16900
```

но должно было получиться

```
1077 1105 1025 1078 1080 1082 1045 1089 1090
```

Вот проверка:

```js
var s = decodeURIComponent(
  "-48 -75 -47 -111 -48 -127 -48 -74 -48 -72 -48 -70 -48 -107 -47 -127 -47 -126"
  .split(" ").map(x => "%" + (x & 255).toString(16)).join("")
)

console.log(s)
console.log(s.split("").map(ch => ch.charCodeAt(0)).join(" "))
```

К тому же, если сделать

```
wchar_t bin[] = {1077, 1105, 1025, 1078, 1080, 1082, 1045, 1089, 1090, 0};
str = bin;
cout << convert.to_bytes(str.c_str()) << endl;
```

то вывод верный.

Код полностью: http://ideone.com/ut7Nsg

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Однако, мне нужна строка в utf16 (wstring).

Это неверно, кодировка `std::wstring` в стандарте не указана,
на Windwows/MSVC `sizeof(wchar_t)` 2, и там кодировка utf-16,
на Linux/gcc `sizeof(wchar_t)` 4 и кодировка utf-32,
ideone использует gcc, отсюда очевидные проблемы, переносимый способ
получить код в utf-16 (c++11):

```
#include <locale>
#include <codecvt>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>

int main() {
    std::wstring_convert < std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<char16_t>, char16_t> convert;

    const char *s = "еёЁжикЕст";
    std::cout << "Input: " << s << "\n";
    std::u16string str = convert.from_bytes(s);
    for (int q=0; s[q]; ++q)
        std::cout << (int)s[q] << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';
    for (int q=0; q<str.length(); ++q)
        std::cout << (int)str[q] << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n'; 
}
```

Comment: Уточню: не UTF-16 и UTF-32, а UCS-2 и UCS-4 соответственно. Разница состоит в отстутсвии у UCS поддержки суррогатных пар. То есть с UCS-2 не получится закодировать часть символов (так называемые Supplementary Characters).

Comment: А обычный `wstring` никак не получится?

Comment: @Qwertiy Для этого нужно использовать `std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>, wchar_t>` (если конечно исходные данные в utf-8), но результат будет именно wstring, `utf-16` не будет.

Comment: Ваш код же выводит ошибку https://ideone.com/YNCcSS

Comment: @Alex78191 Конечно выводит, всё-таки это не Java. Вот правильная ссылка: https://ideone.com/gMtqSd

Comment: @user1034749 ошибся