# Конкатенация const wchar_t* и wchar_t

Tags: c, winapi

Всем привет !

Я использую **const wchar_t*** чтобы получать некоторые данные из сокета, закодированные в UTF-16.

Первая проблема с которой я столкнулся заключалась в том, что у меня не получилось вывести данные в Windows консоль, даже используя **_setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);**

Тем не менее функция, для которой данные были получены (а именно: **CreateFile**), создала файл с правильным именем.

Дальше я должен запустить этот файл, и передать ему аргумент который получу из **GetModuleFileNameW** - путь до самого себя.

Аргумент имеет формат **LPWSTR**, хранится в **wchar_t** и прекрасно выводится в консоль, что для меня кажется странным, разве в **wchar_t** данные не должны храниться в UTF-16 (с выводом которых у меня возникли проблемы) ?

Перед запуском файла (**CreateProcessW**), я должен сложить **const wchar_t*** содержащую имя файла, пробел (**L" "**), кавычки, путь к самому себе (**wchar_t**) и снова кавычки.

Могу ли я использовать **wscncat** для конкатенации без какой-либо предварительной конвертации **const wchar_t** в **wchar_t** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как-то очень расплывчато сформулировано, непонятно даже в чем вопрос состоит.

> разве в wchar_t данные не должны храниться в UTF-16

Должны, хотя и не обязаны. Обычно там хранятся символы в UCS-2 (это практически то же самое, что UTF-16), но программист может использовать такие переменные как угодно. Это же не Кобол какой-нибудь, а С.

Но именно в вашем случае там хранится то, что нужно. Если у вас в консоль выводит неправильно, из этого совсем не следует, что со строкой что-то не то. Консоль в Windows не вполне корректно работает с национальными символами. Или точнее, не совсем предсказуемо.

> Можно ли использовать `wscncat`?

Да, можно.

> Без конвертации `const wchar_t` в `wchar_t`?

Не существует такой конвертации, это одно и то же. Можно только кастом снять атрибут `const`, но на данных это никак не отражается.

---

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ

Еще раз перечитал, и понял, что вы собрались дописывать данные в константную строку. Не стоит так делать, лучше сделайте примерно так:

```
const wchar_t* fileName = L"Здесь имя исполняемого файла";
const wchat_t* appPath = L"Здесь путь к себе";

// Новая длина = fileName + (два символа пробел+кавычка) + appPath + кавычка + завершающий 0
size_t newLen = wcslen(fileName) + 2 + wcslen(appPath) + 1 + 1;
wchar_t* cmd = (wchar_t*)malloc(newLen * sizeof(wchar_t);

wcscpy(cmd, fileName);
wcscat(cmd, L" \"");
wcscat(cmd, appPath);
wcscat(cmd, L"\"");

. . .

free(cmd);
```

Подлиннее, зато корректно и никаких неожиданностей с порчей памяти.

Comment: @rootkit.sys, дополнил ответ.

Comment: Вроде бы неверно. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/671769/178988

Comment: @Qwertiy, не понял - что именно неверно?

Comment: В ответе по ссылке утверждается, что wchar_t может быть utf32.

Comment: @Qwertiy, вопрос же про Windows, какой там UTF-32. Про Линукс речи не было.

Answer (score 0):

Кодировка wchar_t не обязательно UTF16. Может внезапно оказаться, что [она UTF32](//ru.stackoverflow.com/q/671769/178988). Впрочем, вроде бы в Windows такого не замечено, но меня смущает, что одна строка выводится корректно, а другая - нет. Проверь точно по значениям, что там лежит (и что должно лежать), а также кодировку, которую ты устанавливаешь консоли.

Ну и да, не надо записывать данные в readonly-память.

Comment: Давайте все же уточним - 1) `wchar_t` - это не UTF-16. Это тип, который вмещает 16-битный символ, а в какой кодировке - неважно. 2) Windows не использует UTF-16. Для 16-битных символов в Windows используется UCS-2. Отличие небольшое, но при проектировании приложений его все же стоит учитывать. И наконец, 3) в принципе возможен некий 3rd-party компилятор для Windows, в котором `wchar_t` 32-битный. Но там будет столько проблем при вызове функций WinAPI, что сложно такое себе представить.